# roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch crash on ros-electric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The pioneer gazebo example (pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch) from the p2os stack crashes.
I am running it on a Ubuntu 11.04 (64bit) and I used the pre-compiled package installation.
Gazebo starts but crashed because of the libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so

```
Gazebo successfully initialized
[ INFO] [1316529884.396291516]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1316529884.435066390, 0.049000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1316529884.484703223, 0.553000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
ScopedName[robot_description]
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Main simulation loop failed
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 20534, exit code -11].
log files: /home/max/.ros/log/13aa4f40-e397-11e0-ad9d-001fc603da02/gazebo-2*.log
```

It worked on ros diamondback :-(

Any idears
Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11255/roslaunch-p2os_urdf-pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch-crash-on-ros-electric/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-20**:
is pr2_gazebo_plugins (under pr2_simulator stack) installed?  that's where gazebo_ros_controller_manager is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi found my mistake
The package ros-electric-pr2-simulator was not installed.
This package includes the missing lib file libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so

Therfore running

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-simulator
```

solves the problem.

cheers

PS.: The same would would also happen on diamondback

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4